# SQLite no such column

Tags: android, sql, database, android-sqlite

I'm getting no such column exception when creating database to save title, content & sort it by date descending order, i've checked many times and unable to know the reason. My code is

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    //create our table
    String CREATE_WISHES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.TABLE_NAME + "(" +
                                  Constants.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                                Constants.TITLE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                                Constants.CONTENT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                                Constants.DATE_NAME + "  LONG);";
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CREATE_WISHES_TABLE);

}
```

My query statement is as follows:

```
public ArrayList<MyWish> getWishes() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.TITLE_NAME, Constants.CONTENT_NAME,
                    Constants.DATE_NAME}, null, null, null, null, Constants.DATE_NAME + "DESC");
}
```

I'm getting the error in logcat as follows

```
10-27 17:18:04.272  E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: recorddateDESC
10-27 17:18:04.274  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main`
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: recorddateDESC (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, title, content, recorddate FROM wishes ORDER BY recorddateDESC
                                                                          `
```

Comment: Add space in DESC

Comment: can't you see anything strange in your query: `SELECT _id, title, content, recorddate FROM wishes ORDER BY recorddateDESC`

Comment: Thank you, i got it now!

Answer (score 5):

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
```

> A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing
>   or execution.

You should add extra **SPACE** in **`DESC`** Section.

Rectify **SELECT** Statement.

```
 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.TITLE_NAME, Constants.CONTENT_NAME,
                Constants.DATE_NAME}, null, null, null, null, Constants.DATE_NAME + " DESC ");
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Answer (score 2):

You must add a space between the table name and the "DESC"

```
public ArrayList<MyWish> getWishes() {

String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME;

SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME, new String[]{Constants.KEY_ID, Constants.TITLE_NAME, Constants.CONTENT_NAME,
                Constants.DATE_NAME}, null, null, null, null, Constants.DATE_NAME + " DESC");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra space between `Constants.DATE_NAME + " DESC"`. If it still shows the same error

> Uninstall and Install your application.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers here, this can also occur when the column is defined in a trigger. For example, if you see it on trying to delete a row look for erroneous delete triggers in that table.

Answer (score 0):

As per today, with the updated version of Sqlite `string` literals are no longer allowed to be entered with doble quotes `"mystringValue"` but only with single quotes.

Found here [SQLite error 1 "no such column"](https://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift/blob/master/README.md#sqlite-error-1-no-such-column)