# 'no such column' exception in SQLLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to implement a functionality where a button is displayed in the login screen if the user of the app has ever logged in before. If he/she has never logged in before, the button in the login screen is hidden.
What I'm doing is when the user logs in for the first time, the string "LoggedIn" gets stored in my database table - from where I can check if the user has ever logged in before or not, and decide whether to display the button in the login screen or not.

I created a table "LOGGED_IN_STATUS" for this purpose,and 
did the following:

Created the table as:

```
 private final String LOGGED_IN_STATUS_TABLE_CREATE = "create table "+ LOGGED_IN_STATUS + "(" + LOGGED_STATUS + " text default null);";
```

Called it in 'onCreate()' as:

```
database.execSQL(LOGGED_IN_STATUS_TABLE_CREATE);
```

Inserted value into it as:

```
   public String insertIntoLoggedStatus(String status)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + LOGGED_IN_STATUS + "("+LOGGED_STATUS+") VALUES(" + status+");");
        return status;
    }
```

Then,
Called "insertIntoLoggedStatus()" in my 'LoginScreen.java' activity as:

```
loggedInStatus=database.insertIntoLoggedStatus("LoggedIn");
```

The exception I get is:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: LoggedIn
>   (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO LoggedInStatus(LoggedStatus)
>   VALUES(LoggedIn);

I have been trying to solve this for 2 days, but without success.
Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite no such column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975068/sqlite-no-such-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the status is string it must be wrapped with `single quotes`,

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + LOGGED_IN_STATUS + "("+LOGGED_STATUS+") VALUES('" + status+"'));
```

Comment: @Lemmy In addition to Suraj answer, I'd like to add that you can debug this issue in Android Studio by going to View =>Tools Windows=> Device File Explorer.. Inside that under data=>data you can find your package name and inside it there will be the "databases" where you can check your .db file. You will be able to view tables and record in DB Browser for Sqlite. Here is the link https://sqlitebrowser.org/. I hope this helps you well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code,

```
public String insertIntoLoggedStatus(String status){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(LOGGED_STATUS, status);

    db.insert(LOGGED_IN_STATUS, null, values);
}
```